# Trigger count with Alert(right!) message

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a drag and drop feature that tells you whether you have dragged an element to its corresponding Categorie(This part is sorted). I need to also trigger a count for the right answers given each time the corresponding alert fires. Is that possible? In this case i have used the sweet alert library and i can tell text: is the property i want to work with.

Here is the Html/Javascript code for this particular section.

```
if (event.target.className == "dropzone" && dragged.attributes.group.value == event.target.attributes.group.value) {
event.target.style.background = "";
dragged.parentNode.removeChild(dragged);
event.target.appendChild(dragged);
//console.log('test');
swal({
  text: 'RICHTIG!',
  timer: 2000,
  buttons: false,
}).then(
  //where i want to count no. of RICHTIG! triggered using the text property
  function () {},
  //handling the promise rejection
  function (dismiss){
    if (dismiss === 'timer'){
      //console.log('I was closed by the timer')
    }
  }
)
```

}

```
<div>
You have <span id="score">0</span>right answers. 
</div>
```

UPDATE 1: I have a new Jquery code to try and resolve the counter but am getting an Uncaught TypeError $(....).draggable is not a function. This despite having jQuery-ui-touch-punch_min.js, jQuery-ui-custom_min.js and jQuery_min.js defined as a script src in my html.

This is the jQuery code.

```
$(function(){
//set intitial score to 0
var score = 0;
//and put it into the html
$("#score").find("span").html(score);

//increment score
var incrementScore = function(){
    return ++score;
}

//update the score after calling the incrementScore() func
var updateScoreHtml = function(){
    $("#score").find("span").html(incrementScore());
}

$("b-line").draggable({
    hide: function(){
        $(this).hide();
    }
});

$(".dropzone").droppable({
    drop:function (event,ui){
        ui.draggable.hide();
        updateScoreHtml();
    }
});
```

});

HTML:

```
<div id="kategorie">
        <img class="pfeil" draggable="false" src="img/pfeil_breiter-01-01.png" alt="pfeil">
        <img class="dropzone" group="1" id="kategorie1" draggable="false" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" src="img/kategorie1.jpg" alt="kategorie1">
        
        <img class="dropzone" group="2" id="kategorie2" draggable="false" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" src="img/kategorie2.jpg" alt="kategorie2"> 
       
        <img class="dropzone" group="3" id="kategorie3" draggable="false" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" src="img/kategorie3.jpg" alt="kategorie3"> 
    </div>
    <div class="kasten" id="effekte">
        <div class="b-line" id="texte1" group="2" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
            <p>Mitläufereffekt</p>
            <p>Falsche Mehrheit</p>
            <p>Pluralistische Ignoranz</p>
         </div>
        </div>
<div>
You have <span id="score">0</span>right answers. 
</div>
```

UPDATE 2: Uncaught TypeError $(....).draggable is not a function resolved. Still the counter is not executing.

Comment: everything is possible, but what is your problem?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I simply don't know how to go about writing the right function for it. I have already scoured the internet and the best i could come up with are either triggered with an onclick() or windows.onload events.

Comment: just increase a counter when the user entered a correctasnwer.. i dont understand the problem